# Apply DataFormatString in auto generated Telerik RadGridView Cell Specified (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0, dataformat

I have a column which is binded with a property of type `double` in auto generated Telerik RadGridView.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn
         Header="Formated Price" DataFormatString="0.###E0"
         DataMemberBinding="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay}">
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

I want multiple DataFormatString w.r.t Cell.

For example: if value in cell is greater then 5 then "Exponential value" should be shown in the cell, else value should be displayed in "rounded off with two decimal places" in the cell.

Since the table is auto generated, I can't access the single cell value, so I can change its stringFormat

The property `DataFormatString="0.###E0"` applies on complete column, not on a single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do in this case is to not use the default template. Instead, define your own CellTemplate ([GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/p_telerik_windows_controls_gridviewcolumn_celltemplate.html)) and use a [converter on the value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645047%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). The converter would look something like:

```
class PriceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(value);

        if(price > 5.0)
        {
            // return the price formatted how you want
        }
        else
        {
            // return the price formatted differently
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How I can return value in Scientific Notation? 
example: **20.53E+3** in:


`if(price > 5.0)
        {
               
            // return 20.53E+3;
        }`

Comment: Problem to bind with auto generated columns

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx Has all of the .NET string formats. Also, if you are using the CellTemplate, you shouldn't have a problem binding. By the looks of your code, you're using a manually added column, and not the AutoGenerateColumns="True" property.